# Using Disposable Pattern to Clean Up IDispose Member Classes

Tags: c#, dispose, idisposable

Part of the disposable pattern includes the following method.

```
protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
{
    if (!disposed)
    {
        if (disposing)
        {
            // TODO: dispose managed state (managed objects).
        }

        // TODO: free unmanaged resources (unmanaged objects) and override a finalizer below.
        // TODO: set large fields to null.
        disposed = true;
    }
}
```

This method has different handling to clean up managed and unmanaged resources. But what if I want to clean up a class member that implements `IDisposable`?

Normally, I don't know if that member cleans up managed or unmanaged resources. So if I want my `Dispose` method to clean up a class member that implements `IDisposable`, would I call `Dispose()` on that member in the managed or unmanaged sections in the code above?

Comment: You might want to take a look at [Fody.Janitor](https://github.com/Fody/Janitor). It will automagically implement this for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should call Dispose in the managed section (i.e., only when `disposing` is true).

Part of the guidance in [Dispose Pattern](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b1yfkh5e.aspx) under Framework Design Guidelines is:

> The Boolean parameter disposing indicates whether the method was invoked from the IDisposable.Dispose implementation or from the finalizer. The Dispose(bool) implementation should check the parameter before accessing other reference objects [...]. Such objects should only be accessed when the method is called from the IDisposable.Dispose implementation (when the disposing parameter is equal to true). If the method is invoked from the finalizer (disposing is false), other objects should not be accessed. The reason is that objects are finalized in an unpredictable order and so they, or any of their dependencies, might already have been finalized.

Another useful resource is [Implementing a Dispose Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fs2xkftw.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

The standard way of disposing class members that implements `IDisposable` is like this:

```
public class Foo : IDisposable
{
    // MemoryStream implements IDisposable
    private readonly Stream _stream = new MemoryStream();

    private bool _disposed;

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }

    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (_disposed)
        {
            return;
        }

        if (disposing)
        {
            _stream.Dispose();
        }

        _disposed = true;
    }
}
```

To clarify, cleaning up *managed* resources means the resource itself implements `IDisposable` (as `MemoryStream` does above). `MemoryStream`/`Stream` holds the underlying *unmanaged* resource and its cleanup logic is implemented for you already. There is no need to clean up *unmanaged* resources in `Foo`.

Comment: why do you need bool disposing if it's always true ?

Comment: Because for an unsealed class, you can pass `false` to `Dispose(bool)` when the derived class has a finalizer. [Implementing a Dispose method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/standard/garbage-collection/implementing-dispose)